# What is the significance of 吃秋葵时过世?

Tags: chengyu

I found this on nciku.cn and after searching around I could find no other references or even mention. Is this a translation error or some sort of dictionary blip?
I asked a few Chinese friends but they had never heard of it nor any idea to what it could signify aside from one's death.

Comment: Unless it is some form of news headline or has some kind of historical reference, I really don't see any significance of the sentence. I don't recall any related specific usage. I think it is just some random online translation. Maybe someone can give more input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that that at some time *dweg* (or *died while eating gumbo*) has been used in English by some people. Although I can't find many references to it. The definition for dweg can be found on this website: http://www.abbrt.com/dweg

For some reason this ended up in the *Comprehensive English-Chinese Dictionary* which is one of the sources of Nciku. Nciku also has the definition for [dweg](http://www.nciku.com/search/zh/detail/%E5%90%83%E7%A7%8B%E8%91%B5%E6%97%B6%E8%BF%87%E4%B8%96/1850452) and 吃秋葵时过世 is their tranlation of *died while eating gumbo*.

It is definitely not a Chinese expression and not something that is worthwhile learning.

Comment: Since you brought up the idea that it may actually be originated from the English side, I am wondering if it has anything related with the book [Death by Gumbo](http://www.amazon.com/Death-Gumbo-Russo-Mystery-ebook/dp/B004Y00DNQ). Maybe someone was trying to do a translation of the book title?!

Comment: I assumed gumbo was a Chinese dish, since they used okra which I only met in China. Next time I find something as ambiguous I will confirm I know the English definition. Point taken.